# Python Selenium to click element in table that another element is present

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am trying to create a scrapper that enters a website and downloads an XML file containing a balance sheet from real estate funds.

With the code below, I enter a website for a specific fund with document number 07000400000146 (at the end of URL), filter the documents with a search bar on the website, and click to download the first document in the table using XPath.

```
driver.get('https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=07000400000146')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'input[type="search"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'input[type="search"]').send_keys('informe mensal')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tblDocumentosEnviados"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[10]/div/a[2]/i').click()
```

How can I improve this code to click on the download button only for documents with '02/2020' on the column "Data de Referência"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **find_elements_by_xpath** (note the s) to find all elements that match a search.

```
all_rows = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tblDocumentosEnviados"]/tbody/tr')
```

Then you can filter out the rows using:

```
rows_for_feb_2020 = [row for rows in all_rows if (put here a boolean expression to discover if a row is of 02/2020)]
```

Then you can click in each one:

```
map(lambda row: row.find_element_by_xpath(...).click(), rows_for_feb_2020)
```

Comment: the `xpath(...)` should be for what element?

Comment: And can you give me some clues to create the boolean expression you mentioned? This is new for me